# How can I pass one Date to all my class in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, oop

I have problem with my php oop classes 
what i'm doing is 
I'm trying to call some class inside my Run class

```
A , B , C , D classes extends from Run class
```

each of these class has a function to insert the $Date to database 
and each of them need proximately  2 second to execute

What i'm realy need is one Date for all of My class but my problem is  My $Date variable is changeable  I dont know why that is happening

for example 
class A insert 2016-07-16 16:24:55

My problem is class B insert 2016-07-16 16:24:56

and C Will insert 2016-07-16 16:24:57

what i need is To insert 2016-07-16 16:24:55 (one date ) to all the class 
and give final value to $date

> Run class

```
class Run {

       private  $Date;

        public function getDate(){

            return $this->Date;

                        }

function __construct($Date) {

    $this->$Date = $Date;
         new A();
        new B();
       new C();
      new D();

 }


    }
```

> my Main

```
    $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  new Run($Date);
```

> Each Class has insert function

```
function Insert(){
$Date = $this->getDate();
/// and some other stuff 

}
```

Comment: Why do you have four classes that extend the same class?

Comment: because that what i need for  my project the code above is just an example about the real current code I tried to simplify it to understand the problem

Comment: I don't see how 4 child classes of the same class solve one problem.

Comment: that is not our problem for now

Comment: We don't even have a deal, but this question might turn into a XY problem. http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Look Everything works fine when i wrote $Date = " 2016-07-16 16:24:55" and my code work fine 100%  but the problem is when each of these classes executed  they take new date  and this new date not the same as first passing date inside $date

Comment: Post the code of each class

Comment: Ok they are not extend each other  anymore now and they are 2 class  :) I changed the code | this is the problem |

Comment: Your shown main class is not a class, can you please show the real code? Also we need some context, you are just randomly showing us the insert method, but when does it get called, what is supposed to happen and what does currently happen? Why are you actually setting the date in the insert method if you want it to stay the same as you pass it into the object, just remove that line and your problem is gone

Comment: yes the main  is not a class  it's  just a normal file  anyway  I solved the problem by passing the date inside each constructor   I didnt hid anything important what i wrote above is enough to understand the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by passing the $Date inside each constructor and take the value from the class 
but until now i didnt understand why my latest code didnt work

```
 function __construct($Date) {
           new A($Date);
            new B($Date);
           new C($Date);
          new D($Date);

     }
```

Thank you